# shiro validation issue in filter class

Tags: java, weblogic, shiro

I am facing issue with shiro.

We have two applications(two WARS) on the same weblogic server 12c.

One WAR is UI which was integrated with CAS.
Second WAR is Jersey Rest services.

My problem is UI was auntheticated succefully and JsessionID was passed back to Rest Services while communicating with them.
Before reaching to the service we wrote one shiro filter class each time Subject is valid or not.

And also in our UI there is a requirement to call the Rest Service (One specific service) in every one minute.

Issue: Each time call reaches to shiro filter class, we are getting the different subject. i tried to print the sessionId from subject (each time its different), even though user was authenticated successfully in UI and in the backend some time user name is shown as null. Can you pls help.

```
Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
```

Comment: Below is the answers to the above points. As i explained above, for SSO we are using CAS(separate WAR file), for UI is SAP-UI we using(Separate WAR), Jersey Rest Applications(Separate WAR). And also using Shiro filter in both UI and RestServices Applications.First We are login CAS and routed to UI application. And next before landing on UI home page, making the rest call to Rest Service Application by passing JSESSIONID.     JSESSIONID=eHfWJtvzffTVUkh3dtggAfBgW5ptO4LtyT9H_E3Dhj1g9S-y4-Iq!1826731146    1 no login , only org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter 2. No Separate Session mngt

Comment: 1. org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter we are only using this filter , no subject.login. 2 No separate Sesssion Management, as per you documentation planning to use EhCache and will let you know the results.   If any corrections or suggestions pls provide

Comment: dears, thanks for  replying on my question

Comment: One more thing is we are using weblogic 12.2.1.3 cluster environment

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that typically cause this.

1. If you are handing the login yourself (by calling something like `subject.login()` directly, instead of letting the `ShiroFilter` handle it)
2. Both application servers are managing the sessions outside of Shiro: See https://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#session-storage

That said, I'd need more details of how your app is setup. What do your cookies look like, how are your app servers configured, etc.

Comment: Dears, Below is the answers to the above points. 1.org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter